# Filtering results from database with more than one dropdown

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have incorporated a search function to my website that searches all organizations within a certain zip code and selected radius.  This part works well.  I am now trying to incorporate a category search as well, so instead of just searching all organizatios within a selected distance of a zip, it searches all organizations in a selected category within a selected distance of a zip.  However the search is not detecting the selected category.  Any idea why?
Here is the code:

```
<?php include('./Connections/ecsdb.php'); ?>
<script type="text/JavaScript">

function MM_goToURL() { //v3.0
  var i, args=MM_goToURL.arguments; document.MM_returnValue = false;
  for (i=0; i<(args.length-1); i+=2) eval(args[i]+".location='"+args[i+1]+"'");
}

</script>
<?php

mysql_select_db($database_ecsdb, $ecsdb);
$query_getCat = "SELECT DISTINCT category FROM food ORDER BY category DESC";
$getCat = mysql_query($query_getCat, $ecsdb) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getCat = mysql_fetch_assoc($getCat);
$totalRows_getCat = mysql_num_rows($getCat);

?>

<a name="top" id="top"></a>


  <div style="float:right;">

    <?php

    $my_loginbutton =   "<input name=\"toLogin\" type=\"button\"  onclick=\"MM_goToURL('parent','./login/');return document.MM_returnValue\" value=\"Login\" />";
    $my_logoutbutton =  "<input name=\"Logout\" type=\"button\" onclick=\"MM_goToURL('parent','./login/logout.php');return document.MM_returnValue\" value=\"Logout\" />";

    if (isset($_SESSION['MM_Username']))
        echo $my_logoutbutton;
    else
        echo $my_loginbutton;
    ?>

 </div>


  <div id="header" >
 <div style="float:left;"><img name="Alpha Accounting logo" src="./images/banner.png" width="800" height="140" border="0" alt="Alpha Accounting"></div>
 <div style="margin: 10px 0 0 5px; float:left;"></div>
 <div id="search">
 <h2> Search for Organizations</h2>
 <br>


<form action="../caretest/search.php" method="post">

<label name="category">
    Category:
        <select name="category"> 
          <?php
    do {  
    ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $row_getCat['category']?>"><?php echo $row_getCat['category']?></option>
              <?php
    } while ($row_getCat = mysql_fetch_assoc($getCat));
      $rows = mysql_num_rows($getCat);
      if($rows > 0) {
          mysql_data_seek($getCat, 0);
          $row_getCat = mysql_fetch_assoc($getCat);
      }
    ?>
    </select>
    </label>

  <label>Enter your ZIP Code:
  <input maxlength="5" name="zipcode" size="6" type="text" /></label> </br>

 <label>Select a distance:</label>
 <select name="distance">
 <option>5</option>
 <option>10</option>
 <option>25</option>
 <option>50</option>
 <option>100</option>
 </select>

<input name="submit" type="submit" value="search" />


</form>

<?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            if(!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z]{3-50}$/', $_POST['category'])){
                echo "<p><strong>You must select a category. </strong> Please try again.</p>\n";
            }
            if(!preg_match('/^[0-9]{5}$/', $_POST['zipcode'])) {
                echo "<p><strong>You did not enter a properly formatted ZIP Code.</strong> Please try again.</p>\n";
            }
            elseif(!preg_match('/^[0-9]{1,3}$/', $_POST['distance'])) {
                echo "<p><strong>You did not enter a properly formatted distance.</strong> Please try again.</p>\n";
            }
            else {
                //connect to db server; select database
                $link = mysql_connect($hostname_ecsdb, $username_ecsdb, $password_ecsdb) or die('Cannot connect to database server');
                mysql_select_db($database_ecsdb) or die('Cannot select database');

                //query for coordinates of provided ZIP Code
                if(!$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM zip WHERE zip_code = '$_POST[zipcode]'")) {
                    echo "<p><strong>There was a database error attempting to retrieve your ZIP Code.</strong> Please try again.</p>\n";
                }
                else {
                    if(mysql_num_rows($rs) == 0) {
                        echo "<p><strong>No database match for provided ZIP Code.</strong> Please enter a new ZIP Code.</p>\n"; 
                    }
                    else {
                        //if found, set variables
                        $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
                        $lat1 = $row['latitude'];
                        $lon1 = $row['longitude'];
                        $d = $_POST['distance'];
                        $r = 3959;

                        //compute max and min latitudes / longitudes for search square
                        $latN = rad2deg(asin(sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos($d / $r) + cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin($d / $r) * cos(deg2rad(0))));
                        $latS = rad2deg(asin(sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos($d / $r) + cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin($d / $r) * cos(deg2rad(180))));
                        $lonE = rad2deg(deg2rad($lon1) + atan2(sin(deg2rad(90)) * sin($d / $r) * cos(deg2rad($lat1)), cos($d / $r) - sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($latN))));
                        $lonW = rad2deg(deg2rad($lon1) + atan2(sin(deg2rad(270)) * sin($d / $r) * cos(deg2rad($lat1)), cos($d / $r) - sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($latN))));

                        //find all coordinates within the search square's area
                        //exclude the starting point and any empty city values
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM zip WHERE (latitude <= $latN AND latitude >= $latS AND longitude <= $lonE AND longitude >= $lonW) AND (latitude != $lat1 AND longitude != $lon1) AND city != '' ORDER BY state, city, latitude, longitude";
                        if(!$rs = mysql_query($query)) {
                            echo "<p><strong>There was an error selecting nearby ZIP Codes from the database.</strong></p>\n";
                        }
                        elseif(mysql_num_rows($rs) == 0) {
                            echo "<p><strong>No nearby ZIP Codes located within the distance specified.</strong> Please try a different distance.</p>\n";                               
                        }
                        else {
                            //output all matches to screen

                            echo"<br />";
                            echo"<br />";
                            //echo "<h2> Organization Search Results</h2>";

                            echo "<table class=\"bordered\" cellspacing=\"0\">\n";
                            echo"<tr><th></th></tr>\n";
                            echo "<h2> Organization Search Results</h2>";
                            echo"<tr><th></th></tr>\n";

                            echo "<tr><th>Agency</th><th>Telephone</th><th>Hours</th><th>Street Address</th><th>City</th><th>State</th><th>Zip</th><th>Website</th><th>Directions</th></tr>\n";
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
                                //search for matching zip codes in the organization table
                                if(!$rt = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM food WHERE zip = '$row[zip_code]'")){
                                    echo "<p>Didn't work, try again!</p>";
                                    }
                                else{
                                        while($rowt = mysql_fetch_array($rt)) {
                                            //output results
                                            echo "<tr><td>$rowt[Agency]</td><td>$rowt[Telephone]</td><td>$rowt[Hours]</td><td>$rowt[street_address]</td><td>$rowt[city]</td><td>$rowt[state]</td><td>$rowt[zip]</td><td>$rowt[website]</td><td>";
                                            echo "</td></tr>\n";
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                            echo "</table>\n<br />\n";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ?>


</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any query to limit selection of an item by category in the
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
code block. Am I missing something?

Comment: I dont see you querying the categories at all anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

In your Submission portion, you do a regex to check for the existence of the category, but you nothing with it further...

you need to update your query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM zip WHERE (latitude <= $latN AND latitude >= $latS AND longitude <= $lonE AND longitude >= $lonW) AND (latitude != $lat1 AND longitude != $lon1) AND city != '' ORDER BY state, city, latitude, longitude";
```

not really sure how to update the query as I cannot infer the relationships between your food and zip tables.